# How can I make a character take up less horizontal space?

Tags: mathjax

This is the equation, in mathjax:

```
\( sin(\theta)=cos(90°-\theta) \)
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

If you highlight it you can see how much space the degree symbol is taking up:

[image]

How can I get rid of the extra space to the right of the degree symbol so that the equation looks more evenly aligned?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Mathjax is not TeX/LaTeX and this seems to be a pure mathjax question ...

Comment: A better place for `mathjax` questions is StackOverflow. We can't migrate the question, but it will be closed here as off topic.

Comment: BTW, `sin` and `cos` should be replaced by `\sin` and `\cos` to get the normal upright forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\!` to reduce the space:

```
\( \sin(\theta) = \cos(90°\!-\theta) \)
```

Tested on the [demo page](https://www.mathjax.org/#demo) of MathJax:

> [image: Result]